# Get Attribute from XML element

Tags: c#, xml, xmlschema

At the moment we are trying to get the Innertext from a XMLElement where the attribute is EAN.
The only problem is that the XMLElements have the attribute name dt:dt, which can't be found.

We have an XML Schema for this, but how can we import this schema?

`<custom-attribute dt:dt="string" name="EAN">8152210266584</custom-attribute>`

We want the EAN code inside this XMLElement.

And the structure is

Product
-> Custom-attributes
-> Custom-attribute

We have tried to use SelectSingleNodes and LINQ but they only show the elements where there is no dt:dt attribute

Comment: Please post a [mcve] which we can run

Comment: XmlNodeList value = productfile.SelectNodes("//custom-attributes/custom-attribute[@name='EAN']");

Comment: "The name 'productfile' does not exist in the current context". I mean [edit] your question to include a *full* working example which we can copy/paste, and it runs and reproduces your problem straight away, without having to guess what else you're doing. For example, on https://dotnetfiddle.net . Please read [ask]

Comment: [LINQ to XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/linq/linq-xml-overview) may be useful

Comment: did you try `GetAttribute`?

Comment: What is the namespace associated with the namespace prefix `dt`?  Somewhere in the scope of the element `<custom-attribute>` there will be an `xmlns:dt="some-namespace-URI"`.  What is some-namespace-URI?